# Create an object with method using c# reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a problem where I need to create a tfs version control server object using reflection after loading the dll in c#. I'm having trouble initializing it in reflection however as it has no constructors. Without reflection you normally create the object using the getService method in a team project collection object. Here is my code:

```
namespace SendFiletoTFS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String tfsuri = @"uri";
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

            // Load in the assemblies Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
            Assembly tfsclient = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll");
            Assembly versioncontrol = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll");

            // Create Team Project Collection
            Type tpcclass = tfsclient.GetType(@"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection");
            // The 'getService' method.
            MethodInfo getService = tpcclass.GetMethods()[32];
            object tpc = Activator.CreateInstance(tpcclass, new object[] { new Uri(tfsuri), cred });


            Type VersionControlServerClass = versioncontrol.GetType(@"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer");

            // Code I'm trying to emulate in reflection, this is how I would normally do it without reflection.
            //VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            // Create VersionControlServer Class. This line will not work and give a no constructor found exception.
            object vcs = Activator.CreateInstance(VersionControlServerClass, new object[] { tpc });

           //How do I create the vcs object ?
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can create this version control server object using the getService method in the team project collection class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method this way:

```
var closedMethod = getService.MakeGenericMethod(VersionControlServerClass);
object vcs = closedMethod.Invoke(tpc, null);
```

As a note, you should not use something like `tpcclass.GetMethods()[32];` because reflection does not guarantee you the order of the returned methods. Better use `GetMethod([methodname]);`

Comment: Thanks! with the GetMethod([methodname]); I have the problem that there are multiple methods of the same name, thats why I'm trying to access it with getmethods. But that not always in the same order is very scary. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JamesWard You should take this overload then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. If that fails, use GetMethods and use linqs Single method to specify which method you search.

Comment: Exceptionally helpful, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` implements `IServiceProvider`, which actually has non-generic version of GetService:

```
object vcs = ((IServiceProvider)tpc).GetService(VersionControlServerClass);
```

Comment: Oh so very useful! Thank you!